# error 404 with WordPress on ISPConfig3

Tags: wordpress

I had a shared server with Wordpress and now I'm transferring everything to a dedicated server running ISPConfig.

I changed the DNS so that the dedicated server is the one showing the website.
I transferred the entire web folder to the new server (/web/_entire_wp_files_folders)
I also transferred the database.

I can access the new index.php of my website HOWEVER it doesn't show anything ! It's an empty template page.

Worst is that no other page works, giving me a 404 error.

I know the db works fine because I can see the different tags on the footer (plus, I see all my posts and articles on the admin panel).

I checked the /log/error.log file (from ISPConfig)

It says :

```
[Mon Feb 17 08:28:37 2014] [error] [client 82.240.151.74] File does not exist: /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/entreprise
```

Of course this file doesn't exist, because it is a wordpress page (so it is in db)...

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't transfer ALL the files.

I missed the hidden .htaccess file.

Now everything works except the index, but it seems that the db flushed itself for that one page !